# Where to find 64-bit version of Kerio vpn client?

Tags: vpn, 13.10

I need 64-bit version of kerio vpn client. I could not find it on kerio download site. Is there anyone can give me a `.deb` link of it?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** Kerio VPN Client (64 bit) file for Linux. Only (32 bit) version availble.

Beacause that Ubuntu 13.10 is **Multiarch**, this might not be a problem.

I installed it in Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 with this [Kerio-Foums](http://forums.kerio.com/t/17661//) guide.

If you still have a problem in installing do this (in addition to the Installation Instructions);

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb
```

(instead of `sudo dpkg -i kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb`)

But dont try to install `ia32-libs`. That is not in 13.10.

Comment: "sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture kerio-control-vpnclient-8.1.1-1212-p3-linux.deb" Did not work for me. Even when I installed it normally it removes software center and some packages!

Comment: The correct way to add support for 32 bit to a 64 bit system is to use "sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386".  Then you can install the 32 bit application.