# VPN client for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: windows, vpn, connection, client

I was used to use Kerio VPN client **on Windows** for VPN connections.
What client do I have to use? I have no VPN certifications, only host name.
I have host/server name as vpn.abcde.com. Then I type my username abcde\name
and password and I connect remotely to a Virtual Machine. Kerio Control used to
do this for me.
And if someone can tell me the how-to, I would appreciate it!

Comment: You should edit your question to be more specific. When/where did you use Kerio VPN Client and why don't you anymore? What do you mean by VPN certifications? You should probably have some sort of credentials (user/password, certificates, ...). What type of VPN server do you want to connect to?

Comment: edited! really appreciate your comments

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use Kerio from http://download.kerio.com/archive/index.php?type=source, as there seem to be Debian/Ubuntu version.

Have a look at this question [Where to find 64-bit version of Kerio vpn client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361693/kerio-vpn-client-64-bit) should be helpful to you.

Comment: till yesterday, the only Kerio Control I found was for 32-bit Ubuntu.. I'll try now.